# Cannot determine path to 'tools.jar' library for openjdk-18

Tags: java, api, maven, intellij-idea

I am working with Maven for the first time. But I couldn't progress because of the error. I tried many things like Invalidate Caches,  JDK version, Maven version etc. How can I fix it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5LGF.png)

Intellij 2020.02
JDK 14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IntelliJ IDEA version has no support for JDK 18 as this IDE version was released long before JDK 18 which has introduced some changes to the layout and required updated support from the IDE side. Please [update to the current IDE release](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html).

Comment: It works for me. I reinstalled new version IntelliJ IDEA. The error gone.  Thank you so much.